# Списки и срезы в Python

Tags: python, строки, список, срез

Произвольная строка 10-15 символов. Сделать срезы

1. Первые четыре символа
2. Три символа с центра строки
3. Символы с индексом кратным 5

С 1 и 3, вроде как справился, вот не понимаю 2, ибо если непарное количество символов, тогда центр не возможно будет найти. Думал сделать таким путём, что меряет длину(len), проверяет парное или непарное количество строк, потом делит на два и просто вывод числа с эти индексом и двух предыдущих

[image: Мой код]

Comment: Текстовую информацию (код) нужно приводить в вопросе в текстовом виде, а не в виде скриншота.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что тему надо читать перед тем, как делать...

https://ideone.com/rn8yeL

```
s = input()
n = len(s)
print(s[0:4])
print(s[n//2-1:n//2+2])
print(s[::5])
print(s[4::5])
```